# Clojure: NoClassDefFoundError with lein ring uberwar but not when I Compile with the REPL

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I am now experiencing a weird behavior with the [clj-index](https://github.com/ikoblik/clj-index)  library. I have been testing it for some time and everything was working perfectly and as expected when I was compiling my project with the REPL.

The issues started when I was trying to package my application in a WAR file using:

```
lein ring uberwar
```

This always worked for my application until I start using the `clj-index` library.

The error I am getting from Leiningen is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clj_index/core$find_L
 (wrong name: clj_index/core$find_l), compiling:(listener.clj:1:5)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3558)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7226)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7292)
        at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:398)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:438)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
        at clojure.core$compile$fn__5071.invoke(core.clj:5652)
        at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5651)
        at user$eval5.invoke(form-init8409087376793750134.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clj_index/core$find_L (wrong name: cl
j_index/core$find_l)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at clj_index.boyer_moore__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at clj_index.boyer_moore__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clj_index.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at clj_index.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
        at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at umbel.tagger$loading__4958__auto__.invoke(tagger.clj:1)
        at umbel.tagger__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at umbel.tagger__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
        at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
        at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5618)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:619)
        at umbel.core$loading__4958__auto__.invoke(core.clj:1)
        at umbel.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at umbel.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
        at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at umbel.listener$loading__4958__auto__.invoke(listener.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3553)
        ... 29 more
Subprocess failed
```

Then I started looking where the issue may come from. I checked the content of the `/target/classes/` directory. I found that the `cls_index` folder has been created and populated with the *.class files.

I see that the following class files got created:

- `core$find_L$fn__3635.class`
- `core$find_l$fn__3640.class`
- `core$find_L.class`

However, I really don't know:

1. What is the issue
2. Why it is only an issue when generating a WAR file

**Note: I also clearer the target folder using `lein clean` (just in case...) but this has no effect**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because

1. the library uses functions with the same name, but different case, such as `find_l` and `find_L`.
2. your file system is case insensitive

The hint is here:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clj_index/core$find_L 
  (wrong name: clj_index/core$find_l)
```

During compilation the class file for name with one case is overwritten with the classfile for the name with the second case.

This issue only occurs when you force AOT compilation, as when creating a uberwar with `{:aot :all}`.

Comment: @a-webb well, thanks again for the proper answer on one of my question! That make sense since I am on Windows. Is there something I can do to fix that? Probably by fixing the clj-index's code, otherwise, anything else?

Comment: @a-webb Fixing the function name directly from the source worked perfectly, that was indeed the issue I was experiencing. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: @Neoasimov You can also try turning off AOT compilation for the library instead in your `profile.clj`, e.g. start with `{:aot []}`.

Comment: I was coming here to leave the same answer!

Comment: @a-webb great thanks! Will keep that in mind, I didn't realized it was the case by default.